# Python Pandas - how is 25 percentile calculated by describe function

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

For a given dataset in a data frame, when I apply the `describe` function, I get the basic stats which include min, max, 25%, 50% etc.

For example:

```
data_1 = pd.DataFrame({'One':[4,6,8,10]},columns=['One'])
data_1.describe()
```

The output is:

```
        One
count   4.000000
mean    7.000000
std     2.581989
min     4.000000
25%     5.500000
50%     7.000000
75%     8.500000
max     10.000000
```

**My question is**: What is the mathematical formula to calculate the 25%?

1) Based on what I know, it is:

```
formula = percentile * n (n is number of values)
```

In this case:

```
25/100 * 4 = 1
```

So the first position is number 4 but according to the describe function it is `5.5`.

2) Another example says - if you get a whole number then take the average of 4 and 6 - which would be 5 - still does not match `5.5` given by describe.

3) Another tutorial says - you take the difference between the 2 numbers - multiply by 25% and add to the lower number:

```
25/100 * (6-4) = 1/4*2 = 0.5
```

Adding that to the lower number: `4 + 0.5 = 4.5`

Still not getting `5.5`.

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: isn't this the `(max - min)/4`? so 10-4 = 6 then divide by 4 gives 1.5 which you then set as the interval between 4 and 10?

Comment: I think it internally uses numpy,  check the percentil code here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b91e8d8f164731bb710cc1e5173cc8ec3f8fadf5/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3796

Comment: The beauty of open source is that you can check the code yourself. According to the [code of `describe`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/37f95cef85834207db0930e863341efb285e38a2/pandas/core/generic.py#L5181), it calls series' [`quantile` method](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/37f95cef85834207db0930e863341efb285e38a2/pandas/core/series.py#L1345). The docstring has your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [pandas documentation](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py) there is information about the computation of quantiles, where a reference to numpy.percentile is made:

> Return value at the given quantile, a la numpy.percentile.

Then, checking numpy.percentile [explanation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html), we can see that the interpolation method is set to **linear** by default:

> linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part
>   of the index surrounded by i and j

For your specfic case, the 25th quantile results from:

```
res_25 = 4 + (6-4)*(3/4) =  5.5
```

For the 75th quantile we then get:

```
res_75 = 8 + (10-8)*(1/4) = 8.5
```

If you set the interpolation method to "midpoint", then you will get the results that you thought of.

.

Answer (score 8):

I think it's easier to understand by seeing this calculation as **min+(max-min)*percentile**. It has the same result as this function described in NumPy:

> linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j

```
res_25 = 4+(10-4)*percentile = 4+(10-4)*25% = 5.5
res_75 = 4+(10-4)*percentile = 4+(10-4)*75% = 8.5
```

Comment: But why would you use 10 instead of 6?

Comment: As Orli said, its min+(max-min)*percentile. So, its 4+(10-4)*percentile

Comment: I tried to understand, but the results with this formula and the method percentile are different:

my_data = [2.3, 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 4.2, 4.5]
print(np.percentile(my_data, 25))
print(np.percentile(my_data, 75))