# Is pandas showing the wrong percentile?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm working with this WNBA dataset [here](https://www.kaggle.com/jinxbe/wnba-player-stats-2017). I'm analyzing the `Height` variable, and below is a table showing frequency, cumulative percentage, and cumulative frequency for each height value recorded:

[image: img]

From the table I can easily conclude that the first quartile (the 25th percentile) cannot be larger than 175.

However, when I use `Series.describe()`, I'm told that the 25th percentile is 176.5. Why is that so?

```
wnba.Height.describe()
count    143.000000
mean     184.566434
std        8.685068
min      165.000000
25%      176.500000
50%      185.000000
75%      191.000000
max      206.000000
Name: Height, dtype: float64
```

Comment: As many said, there are various ways to get a percentile. If you need to get 175 you can have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49025713/3941704)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways to estimate the quantiles.
The 175.0 vs 176.5 relates to two different methods:

1. Includes the Q1 ( this gives 176.5) and
2. Excludes the Q1( gives 175.0).

The estimation differs as follows

```
#1
h = (N − 1)*p + 1 #p being 0.25 in your case
Est_Quantile =  x⌊h⌋ + (h − ⌊h⌋)*(x⌊h⌋ + 1 − x⌊h⌋)

#2
h = (N + 1)*p   
x⌊h⌋ + (h − ⌊h⌋)*(x⌊h⌋ + 1 − x⌊h⌋)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a statistics problem. There are many definitions of percentile. Here is one explanation why you would add 1 in calculating your 25th percentile index:

> One intuitive answer is that the average of the numbers 1 through n is
>   not n/2 but rather (n+1)/2. So this gives you a hint that simply using
>   p*n would produce values that are slightly too small.

Resources:

- [Why add one to the number of observations when calculating percentiles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525175/why-add-one-to-the-number-of-observations-when-calculating-percentiles)
- [Why the plus one in the percentile formula p(n+1)?](http://www.pmean.com/07/PercentileFormula.html)

Answer (score 1):

That is because by default `describe()` does a linear interpolation.

So, **no `pandas` is not showing the wrong percentile**
(it is just not showing the percentile you want to see).

To get what you expect you can use `.quantile()` on `Height` series, specifying interpolation to `'lower'` :

```
df = pd.read_csv('../input/WNBA Stats.csv')
df.Height.quantile(0.25,interpolation='lower') #interpolation lower to get what you expect
```

See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html) for more options.

---

Note that as [@jpp said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49025608/3941704):

> There are many definitions of percentile

You can see this [answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39568222/3941704) that talks about differences between `numpy` and `pandas` percentiles calculation for instance.